# java codility Frog-River-One

Tags: java, algorithm

I have been trying to solve a Java exercise on a Codility web page.

Below is the link to the mentioned exercise and my solution.

https://codility.com/demo/results/demoH5GMV3-PV8

Can anyone tell what can I correct in my code in order to improve the score?

**Just in case here is the task description:**

A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is currently located at position 0, and wants to get to position X. Leaves fall from a tree onto the surface of the river.

You are given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers representing the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls at time K, measured in minutes.

The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at every position across the river from 1 to X.

For example, you are given integer X = 5 and array A such that:

```
  A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 3
  A[6] = 5
  A[7] = 4
```

In minute 6, a leaf falls into position 5. This is the earliest time when leaves appear in every position across the river.

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int X, int[] A); }
```

that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers and integer X, returns the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river.

If the frog is never able to jump to the other side of the river, the function should return −1.

For example, given X = 5 and array A such that:

```
  A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 3
  A[6] = 5
  A[7] = 4
```

the function should return 6, as explained above. Assume that:

```
N and X are integers within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..X].
```

Complexity:

```
expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(X), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

Elements of input arrays can be modified.

**And here is my solution:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Solution {

    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        int list[] = A;
        int sum = 0;
        int searchedValue = X;

        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int iii = 0; iii < list.length; iii++) {

            if (list[iii] <= searchedValue && !arrayList.contains(list[iii])) {
                sum += list[iii];
                arrayList.add(list[iii]);
            }
            if (list[iii] == searchedValue) {
                if (sum == searchedValue * (searchedValue + 1) / 2) {
                    return iii;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put your problem in your question, otherwise if that link goes down, this question becomes useless.

Comment: For example, given X = 7 and array A such that:

  A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 5 
the function should return 3, could you explain as well ?

Comment: Wow, and I thought that using set is a cheating...

Comment: Can someone explain this question? Sorry but I didn't get the question

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are using `arrayList.contains` inside a loop, which will traverse the whole list unnecessarily.

Here is my solution (I wrote it some time ago, but I believe it scores 100/100):

```
    public int frog(int X, int[] A) {
        int steps = X;
        boolean[] bitmap = new boolean[steps+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if(!bitmap[A[i]]){
                bitmap[A[i]] = true;
                steps--;
                if(steps == 0) return i;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: It gives 100/100, But when I have int A[] = {6,4,3,2,1,5}; int steps = 5; 
I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6  
I believe you have to omit values that A[i] > X;

Comment: The spec said that array A only contains elements in range [1,X] so the code is valid I think. Always read the spec very carefully, sometimes some constraint can lead you to solve a problem in a way you wouldn't have thought of without it. You should also accept answers if you think they helped you.

Comment: For example, given X = 7 and array A such that:

  A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 5 
the function should return 3, could you explain as well ?

Comment: modified this code a bit to make it 100/100 solution. added a 'if' condition that filters out the invalid input case of A.length<X - 

 public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
  if (A.length >= X) {
   long total = X;
   boolean[] bitmap = new boolean[A.length+1];

   for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (!bitmap[A[i]]) {
     bitmap[A[i]] = true;
     total--;
     if (total == 0)
      return i;
    }
   }
  }
  return -1;
 }

Comment: @QuestMonger is my code no longer 100/100 without that check? It was before, but maybe the test cases were updated. I would be surprised if it didn't pass though since the array has at most 100k elements, not that many.

Comment: @rafalio - It wasnt a few days ago, but i ran it again today and it now says 100/100. https://codility.com/demo/results/demoGAUPBB-KCA/

maybe i am seeing things :).

Comment: @rafalio, Space complexity is not correct in your answer. "expected worst-case space complexity is O(X)" but you have define a array of X+1.

Answer (score 20):

Here is my solution. It got me 100/100:

```
public int solution(int X, int[] A)
{
     int[] B = A.Distinct().ToArray();
     return (B.Length != X) ? -1 : Array.IndexOf<int>(A, B[B.Length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: This code does not even compile. Is it in Java?

Comment: This is C#, don't forget to add
`using System.Linq;`
at the top

Answer (score 8):

100/100

```
public static int solution (int X, int[] A){

    int[]counter = new int[X+1];
    int ans = -1;
    int x = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
        if (counter[A[i]] == 0){
            counter[A[i]] = A[i];
            x += 1;
            if (x == X){
                return i;
            }
        } 
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A Java solution using Sets (Collections Framework) Got a 100%

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class Froggy {
    public static int solution(int X, int[] A){
    int steps=-1;
    Set<Integer> values = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<A.length;i++){
        if(A[i]<=X){
            values.add(A[i]);
        }
        if(values.size()==X){
            steps=i;
            break;
        }
    }
        return steps;
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to break. just return immediate after you find the steps

Answer (score 6):

Better approach would be to use `Set`, because it only adds unique values to the list. Just add values to the `Set` and decrement `X` every time a new value is added, (`Set#add()` returns `true` if value is added, `false` otherwise);
have a look,

```
public static int solution(int X, int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (values.add(A[i])) X--; 
        if (X == 0) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

do not forget to import,

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution, scored 100/100:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        HashSet<Integer> hset = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i] <= X)
               hset.add(A[i]);   
            if (hset.size() == X)
               return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution 100%

```
public int solution(final int X, final int[] A) {

Set<Integer> emptyPosition = new HashSet<Integer>();

for (int i = 1; i <= X; i++) {
  emptyPosition.add(i);
}
// Once all the numbers are covered for position, that would be the
// moment when the frog will jump
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  emptyPosition.remove(A[i]);
  if (emptyPosition.size() == 0) {
    return i;
  }
}
return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution.
It isn't perfect, but it's good enough to score 100/100.
(I think that it shouldn't have passed a test with a big A and small X)

Anyway, it fills a new `counter` array with each leaf that falls

counter has the size of X because I don't care for leafs that fall farther than X, therefore the try-catch block.

AFTER X leafs fell (because it's the minimum amount of leafs) I begin checking whether I have a complete way - I'm checking that every int in count is greater than 0.
If so, I return i, else I break and try again.

```
public static int solution(int X, int[] A){
    int[] count = new int[X];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        try{
            count[A[i]-1]++;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){ }
        if (i >= X - 1){
            for (int j = 0; j< count.length; j++){
                if (count[j] == 0){
                    break;
                }
                if (j == count.length - 1){
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution with 100 / 100.

```
public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
    int len = A.length;
    if (X > len) {
        return -1;
    }
    int[] isFilled = new int[X];
    int jumped = 0;
    Arrays.fill(isFilled, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int x = A[i];
        if (x <= X) {
            if (isFilled[x - 1] == 0) {
                isFilled[x - 1] = 1;
                jumped += 1;
                if (jumped == X) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I have in C#. It can probably still be refactored.
We throw away numbers greater than X, which is where we want to stop, and then we add numbers to an array if they haven't already been added.
When the count of the list has reached the expected number, X, then return the result. 100%

```
        var tempArray = new int[X+1];
        var totalNumbers = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] > X || tempArray.ElementAt(A[i]) != 0)
                continue;
            tempArray[A[i]] = A[i];
            totalNumbers++;

            if (totalNumbers == X)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
```

Answer (score 3):

below is my solution. I  basically created a set which allows uniques only and then go through the array and add every element to set and keep a counter to get the sum of the set and then using the sum formula of consecutive numbers then I got 100% . Note : if you add up the set using java 8 stream api the solution is becoming  quadratic and you get %56 .

```
public static int solution2(int X, int[] A) {

    long sum = X * (X + 1) / 2;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int setSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (set.add(A[i]))
            setSum += A[i];

        if (setSum == sum) {
            return i;
        }

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My JavaScript solution that got 100 across the board. Since the numbers are assumed to be in the range of the river width, simply storing booleans in a temporary array that can be checked against duplicates will do. Then, once you have amassed as many numbers as the quantity X, you know you have all the leaves necessary to cross.

```
function solution(X, A) {
    covered = 0;
    tempArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (!tempArray[A[i]]) {
            tempArray[A[i]] = true;
            covered++
            if(covered === X) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer in Python:

```py
def solution(X, A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    values = set()
    for i in range (len(A)):
        if A[i]<=X :
            values.add(A[i])
        if len(values)==X:
            return i
    return -1
```

Answer (score 2):

C# Solution with 100% score:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        // go through the array
        // fill a hashset, until the size of hashset is X
        var set = new HashSet<int>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var a in A)
        {
            if (a <= X)
            {
                set.Add(a);
            }
            if (set.Count == X)
            {
                return i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this problem as well and here is my solution. Basically, I just declared an array whose size is equal to position X. Then, I declared a counter to monitor if the necessary leaves have fallen at the particular spots. The loop exits when these leaves have been met and if not, returns -1 as instructed.

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        int size = A.length;
        int[] check = new int[X];
        int cmp = 0;
        int time = -1;

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            int temp = A[x];
            if (temp <= X) {
                if (check[temp-1] > 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                check[temp - 1]++;
                cmp++;
            }

            if ( cmp == X) {
                time = x;
                break;
            }
        }

        return time;
    }
}
```

It got a 100/100 on the evaluation but I'm not too sure of its performance. I am still a beginner when it comes to programming so if anybody can critique the code, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not perfect but its straightforward. Just made a counter Array to track the needed "leaves" and verified on each iteration if the path was complete. Got me 100/100 and O(N).

```
    public static int frogRiver(int X, int[] A)
    {
        int leaves = A.Length;
        int[] counter = new int[X + 1];
        int stepsAvailForTravel = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < leaves; i++)
        {
            //we won't get to that leaf anyway so we shouldnt count it,
            if (A[i] > X)
            {
                continue;
            } 
            else
            {
                //first hit!, keep a count of the available leaves to jump
                if (counter[A[i]] == 0)
                    stepsAvailForTravel++;

                counter[A[i]]++;

            }
            //We did it!!
            if (stepsAvailForTravel == X)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. I think it's very simple. It gets 100/100 on codibility.
set.contains() let me eliminate duplicate position from table. 
The result of first loop get us expected sum. In the second loop we get sum of input values.

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {

        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= X; i++){
            sum1 += i;       
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if (set.contains(A[i])) continue;
            set.add(A[i]);
            sum2 += A[i];
            if (sum1 == sum2) return i;
        }        
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is perfect except below code
Your code returns value only if list[iii] matches with searchedValue.

The algorithm must be corrected in such a way that, it returns the value if sum == n * ( n + 1) / 2.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        int list[] = A;
        int sum = 0;
        int searchedValue = X;
        int sumV = searchedValue * (searchedValue + 1) / 2;   
        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int iii = 0; iii < list.length; iii++) {
            if (list[iii] <= searchedValue && !arrayList.contains(list[iii])) {
                sum += list[iii];
                if (sum == sumV) {
                    return iii;
                }
                arrayList.add(list[iii]);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I think you need to check the performance as well. I just ensured the output only

Answer (score 1):

This solution I've posted today gave 100% on codility, but respectivly @rafalio 's answer it requires K times less memory

```java
public class Solution {

    private static final int ARRAY_SIZE_LOWER = 1;
    private static final int ARRAY_SIZE_UPPER = 100000;
    private static final int NUMBER_LOWER = ARRAY_SIZE_LOWER;
    private static final int NUMBER_UPPER = ARRAY_SIZE_UPPER;

    public static class Set {

        final long[] buckets;

        public Set(int size) {
            this.buckets = new long[(size % 64 == 0 ? (size/64) : (size/64) + 1)];
        }

        /**
         * number should be greater than zero
         * @param number
         */
        public void put(int number) {
            buckets[getBucketindex(number)] |= getFlag(number); 
        }

        public boolean contains(int number) {
            long flag = getFlag(number);
            // check if flag is stored
            return (buckets[getBucketindex(number)] & flag) == flag;
        }

        private int getBucketindex(int number) {
            if (number <= 64) {
                return 0;
            } else if (number <= 128) {
                return 1;
            } else if (number <= 192) {
                return 2;
            } else if (number <= 256) {
                return 3;
            } else if (number <= 320) {
                return 4;
            } else if (number <= 384) {
                return 5;
            } else 
                return (number % 64 == 0 ? (number/64) : (number/64) + 1) - 1;
        }

        private long getFlag(int number) {
            if (number <= 64) {
                return 1L << number;
            } else
                return 1L << (number % 64);
        }
    }

    public static final int solution(final int X, final int[] A) {
        if (A.length < ARRAY_SIZE_LOWER || A.length > ARRAY_SIZE_UPPER) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Array size out of bounds");
        }
        Set set = new Set(X);
        int ai;
        int counter = X;
        final int NUMBER_REAL_UPPER = min(NUMBER_UPPER, X);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < A.length; i++) {
            if ((ai = A[i]) < NUMBER_LOWER || ai > NUMBER_REAL_UPPER) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Number out of bounds");
            } else if (ai <= X && !set.contains(ai)) {
                counter--;
                if (counter == 0) {
                    return i;
                }
                set.put(ai);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static int min(int x, int y) {
        return (x < y ? x : y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution it got me 100/100 and O(N).

```
public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> leaves = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = A.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        leaves.put(A[i] - 1, i);
    }

    return leaves.size() != X ? -1 : Collections.max(leaves.values());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
public func FrogRiverOne(_ X : Int, _ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {

    var B = [Int](repeating: 0, count: X+1)

    for i in 0..<A.count {
        if B[A[i]] == 0 {
            B[A[i]] = i+1
        }
    }

    var time = 0

    for i in 1...X {
        if( B[i] == 0 ) {
            return -1
        } else {
            time = max(time, B[i])
        }
    }

    return time-1
}

A = [1,2,1,4,2,3,5,4]
print("FrogRiverOne: ", FrogRiverOne(5, &A))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I re-wrote this exercise without seeing my last answer and came up with another solution 100/100 and O(N).

```
public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> leaves = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i=0; i < A.length; i++) {
        leaves.add(A[i]);

        if (leaves.contains(X) && leaves.size() == X)  return i; 
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I like this one better because it is even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

This one works good on codality 100% out of 100%. It's very similar to the marker array above but uses a map:

```
  public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
    int index = -1;

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      if (!map.containsKey(A[i])) {
        map.put(A[i], A[i]);
        X--;
        if (X == 0) {index = i;break;}
      }
    }

    return index;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

%100 with js

```
function solution(X, A) {

  let leafSet = new Set();

  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i += 1) {

    if(A[i] <= 0) 
        continue;

    if (A[i] <= X )
        leafSet.add(A[i]); 


    if (leafSet.size == X)
      return i;

  }

  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript following solution got 100/100.

Detected time complexity: O(N)

```
function solution(X, A) {
    let leaves = new Set();

    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] <= X) {
            leaves.add(A[i])
            if (leaves.size == X) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

100% Solution using Javascript.

[image]

```
function solution(X, A) {
    if (A.length === 0) return -1
    if (A.length < X) return -1


    let steps = X
    const leaves = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (!leaves[A[i]]) {
            leaves[A[i]] = true
            steps--
        }

        if (steps === 0) {
            return i
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingXE7QFJ-TZ7/

I have a very simple solution (100% / 100%) using HashSet. Lots of people check unnecessarily whether the Value is less than or equal to X. This task cannot be otherwise.

```
public static int solution(int X, int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> availableFields = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        availableFields.add(A[i]);
        if (availableFields.size() == X){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int solutions(int X, int[] A) {
        Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (values.add(A[i])) {
                X--; 
            }
            if (X == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Understanding this problem took a while for me, I would like to explain in simple words

1. We can only take a unique step, no step can be repeated.
2. Consider only the unique step because duplicate should not count, therefore I am increasing the steps counter by 1 if and only if I have not considered it once.
3. Now since we have reached on the actual value, we have to add by 1 so as to cross the hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It uses 3 loops but is constant time and gets 100/100 on codibility.

```
class FrogLeap
{
    internal int solution(int X, int[] A)
    {
        int result = -1;
        long max = -1;
        var B = new int[X + 1];

        //initialize all entries in B array with -1
        for (int i = 0; i <= X; i++)
        {
            B[i] = -1;
        }

        //Go through A and update B with the location where that value appeared
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
           if( B[A[i]] ==-1)//only update if still -1
            B[A[i]] = i;
        }

        //start from 1 because 0 is not valid
        for (int i = 1; i <= X; i++)
        {
            if (B[i] == -1)
                return -1;
            //The maxValue here is the earliest time we can jump over
            if (max < B[i])
                max = B[i];
        }

        result = (int)max;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet C++ code. Gets perfect 100%... Drum roll ... [image]

```
#include <set>
int solution(int X, vector<int> &A) {
    set<int> final;
    for(unsigned int i =0; i< A.size(); i++){
        final.insert(A[i]);
        if(final.size() == X) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
     Set<Integer> positionsCovered = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
//Set covering the leaves fallen to keep track of the distance to destination   

        if(X == 1)
             return 0 ;
       int position = 0;     
       for(int i = 0; i < A.length -1 ;i++ ) {       
           if(A[i] <= X && A[i] > 1 && positionsCovered.size() < (X-1)) { 
      //X-1 as we start from 1
               positionsCovered.add(A[i]);
           }
           if(positionsCovered.size()== (X-1)) {
               position = i ;
            break;
           }
       }         
        return position != 0 ? position : -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This loops array A and inserts data to array B (1) to every position that the content in A points to..

If A[0] = 4, then at B[4-1] = 1, do this until var = X.

```
public static int bestSolution(int X, int[] A) {
        int[] B = new int[X];
        int var = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            int content = A[i];
            if (B[content - 1] == 0) {
                B[content - 1] = 1;
                var++;
            }
            if(var == X){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another 100% Score whith Java:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        int leafs[] = new int[X];
        int count = X;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {   
            if (leafs[A[i]-1] != 1)
            {
                leafs[A[i]-1] = 1;
                count--;
            }
            if (count == 0)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Frogt Reiver One Codility 10%](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingQ28RU6-FFE/)

With little explanation in python codility 100 %

```
def solution(X, A):
"""
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingQ28RU6-FFE/
100%
idea is use array item as K_index in covered time array
covered time array set the value to be covered as soon as it finds some value
if position is already covered it checks for all items in array until any of the item in array can be covered
:param X:
:param A:
:return:
"""
# assume all position is covered
covered_time = [-1] * X
for K_index in range(0, len(A)):
    print("Covered position count " + str(X))
    print(X)
    print(covered_time)
    if covered_time[A[K_index] - 1] != -1:
        # A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls at time K
        # position is already covered
        # time is being spent
        continue
    else:
        # This position is to be covered
        # cover this position ie. make array element with marker(array value)
        covered_time[A[K_index] - 1] = K_index
        # reduce position to be cover
        X -= 1
        # as soon as positions are covered return
        if X == 0:
            # now all positions are covered
            return K_index
# if we are here it means time spent but we can not cover all positions
return -1


result = solution(5, [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4])
print("Sol " + str(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a unique solution [ already not listed in above using multi map  in C++].
This scores 100% on codility and detected big(O) complexity is O(N). Esentially build a multi map of position and list of times [ i.e seconds ] at which leaves fall at that position.

```
int solution(int targetPos, vector<int>& A)
{
  if(!A.size())
    return(-1);

  multimap<int, int> positionMap;
  bool insertStatus=false;
  for(size_t i=0;i<A.size();++i)
  {
    positionMap.insert(pair<int, int>(A[i], i));
    if(targetPos==A[i])
      insertStatus=true;
  }

  if(!insertStatus)
    return(-1);

  int currMax=-1;
  for(int i=1; i<=targetPos;++i)
  {
    auto iter=positionMap.equal_range(i);
    if(!distance(iter.first, iter.second))
      return(-1);

    int currMin=INT_MAX;
    for(auto it=iter.first; it!=iter.second; ++it)
    {
      if(it->second<currMin)
        currMin=it->second;
    }
    if(currMin>currMax)
      currMax=currMin;
  }

  return(currMax);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution would be easy to understand.
If you need to know elaborate . Please let me know which part do you want to know.

```
    static int solution(int x, int[]a){

    int currentPosition = 0;//The frog is initially located on one bank of the river (position 0) 
    int[] opositPostion = new int[x+1];//wants to get to the opposite bank (position X+1). 

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

        if (opositPostion[a[i]]== 0){
            opositPostion[i] = a[i];
            currentPosition += 1;
        }
        if (currentPosition == x){//The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river.
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<Integer> _hashset = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int occupiedPositions = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            if(A[i] <= X && _hashset.add(A[i]))
            {
                occupiedPositions++;
            }

            if (occupiedPositions == X)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another C# approach (similar to that used by Kamlesh Shewani):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Solution {
        public int solution(int X, int[] A)
        {
            var set = new HashSet<int>(A);
            return set.Count != X ? -1 : Array.IndexOf<int>(A, new List<int>(set)[new List<int>(set).Count-1]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another answer using hashsets in Java with 100/100 score.

```
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {            
        Set<Integer> positions = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if(A[i] <= X)
                positions.add(A[i]);
            if(positions.size() == X)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Python #

I am using OrderedDict from collections and sum of first n numbers to check whether the frog will be able to cross or not.

```
def solution(X, A):
    from collections import OrderedDict as od
    if sum(set(A))!=(X*(X+1))//2:
        return -1
    k=list(od.fromkeys(A).keys())[-1]
    for x,y in enumerate(A):
        if y==k:
            return x
```

Answer (score 0):

in C#

```
public static int solution(int X, int[] A)
{
    HashSet<int> hash = new HashSet<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] <= X)
        {
            hash.Add(A[i]);

            if (hash.Count == X)
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript to gain 100% score follow this solution!! I have used Set()

```
    function solution(X, A) {
    
        let Position = new Set();
        let n = A.length;
        for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
             Position.add(A[i]);
             if(Position.size==X)
               return i;
        }
       if(Position.size!=X){
         return -1;  
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for swift 100%

```
public func solution(_ X : Int, _ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
        var main = Set(1...X)
        for (index,item) in A.enumerated(){
            if let _ = main.remove(item){
                if main.count == 0{
                    return index
                }
            }
        }
        return -1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java solution. 100% success on codility

```
 public int solution(int X, int[] A) {

        boolean[] counter = new boolean[X + 1];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

            if (counter[A[i]] == false) {
                counter[A[i]] = true;
                count++;
                if (count == X) {
                    return i;
                }
            }


        }
        
        return -1;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution with C++:

```
#include <algorithm>
int solution(int X, vector<int> &A) 
{
    vector<bool> boolVec (X,false);
    if(A.size()>0)
    {
       for(unsigned int i=0; i<=A.size()-1; i++)
       {
          // Find in boolean vector
          if (boolVec[A[i]-1] != true)
          {
             boolVec[A[i]-1] = true;
          }
          // All steps done?
          if (all_of(boolVec.begin(), boolVec.end(), [](bool i){return i; }))
          {
             return i;
          }
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution utilizes 2 Sets to compute the solution. Time complexity **O(N)**

```
public int solution(int[] A, int X) {
    Set<Integer> requiredLeavesSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= X; i++) {
        requiredLeavesSet.add(i);
    }
    Set<Integer> currentLeavesSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        currentLeavesSet.add(A[i]);
        if (currentLeavesSet.size() < requiredLeavesSet.size()) continue;

        if (currentLeavesSet.containsAll(requiredLeavesSet)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

JUnit5 Test Case:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("createData")
void solutionTest(int numberOfSteps, int[] testInputArray, int expectedValue) {
    assertEquals(expectedValue, frogRiverOne.solution(testInputArray, numberOfSteps));
}

public static Object [][] createData() {
    return new Object [][] {
            new Object [] { 5, new int [] {             1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4 },  6 },
            new Object [] { 3, new int [] {                               1, 3 }, -1 }, //never gets across
            new Object [] { 2, new int [] {                         1, 1, 1, 1 }, -1 }, //never gets across
            new Object [] { 3, new int [] {                         1, 4, 2, 3 },  3 },
            new Object [] { 2, new int [] {                         1, 4, 2, 3 },  2 },
            new Object [] { 4, new int [] { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1 },  9 },
            new Object [] { 4, new int [] { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1 },  8 },
            new Object [] { 4, new int [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1 },  3 },
    };
}
```

Analysis:
[Codility Analysis Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utwBn.png)

Answer (score 0):

My solution (score = 100)

```
import java.util.*;

public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> pos = new HashSet<>();
    int highestTime = 0;
    // Adding to the Set only positions with minimal times
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if(!pos.contains(A[i])){
            if(A[i] > X) {
                continue;
            }
            pos.add(A[i]);
            if(i > highestTime) {
                highestTime = i;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!pos.contains(X)) {
        return -1;
    }

    // if positions are not consecutive, the frog cannot cross the river
    for(int p = 1; p <= X; p++){
        if(!pos.contains(p)){
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return highestTime;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 private static int FrogRiverOne(int X, int[] A)
        {
            HashSet<int> occ = new HashSet<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                if (A[i] <= X)
                {
                    occ.Add(A[i]);
                }
                if (occ.Count == X)
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;}
```

Comment: Provide also a text description to your solution

Answer (score -1):

Javascript solution

```
function solution(X, A) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
    let minTime = -1;
    
    //initial positions with leafs
    let posFilled = Array(X+1).fill(false);
    let totalFilled = 0;

    for(let i=0; i<A.length; i++){
        let step = A[i];
        
        //if already filled, don't add to total filled
        if(step <= X && !posFilled[step]) {
            posFilled[step] = true;
            
            //increment total filled
            totalFilled += 1;
        }

        //if all have been filled, set min time and break        
        if(totalFilled === X){
            minTime = i;
            
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return minTime;
}
```

Comment: The question asks about Java specifically, so your solution seems off-topic.